Expand templates to text in wikipedia
I have some custom wikitext(which also includes templates) and need to convert to text.
To do this, I use wikiexpand.
In the README file it is indicated:
Modules written in Lua and executed using {{#invoke:}} are not recognised, but can be replaced by implementing callable templates (that is, functions that render Wikicode)
The documentation in wikiexpand.expand.templates.TemplateStore.callable_templates is not very explicit.
Would it be possible to help me by giving me an example implementation?
For example, for the following wikicode:
{{ISBN|978-2-84066-599-1}}
{{Date de naissance|11|novembre|1866}}


I guess what the documentation says is it cannot expand lua templates, but only 'normal' wikicode ones.
A solution could be tu use the pre-lua versions of templates, like the wikicode of the 2012 version of {{Date de naissance}}.
If it concerns wp.fr, you'll probably have better and quicker answers on Discussion Projet:Modèle.
